# Scoreboard with negative value in multidimensional array giving an exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been stuck.

I am doing currently a scoreboard.

I have a problem on my code that's a little bit irritating

```
string[,] table = new string[104, 15];
int xIndex = 0;
int yIndex = 0;
string newPrevious = "placeholder";
//P = BLUE, B = RED, T = GREEN
string[] strData = { "B  ,T  ,P  ,P B,T  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,T  ,B  ,P  " };

 for (int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++)
    {
        OriginalData += strData[i];
        OriginalData += ",";
    }
    string[] newNewData = OriginalData.Split(',');
    string result = "";
    string previous = "";
    int counterForTie = 0;
    foreach (string newStrData in newNewData)
    {
        Debug.Log("This is the data : " + newStrData);

        GameObject o = Instantiate(prefab_gameobject) as GameObject;
        o.transform.SetParent(pos_big_road);
        o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        img = (RawImage)o.GetComponent<RawImage>();

        //check the length so that it won't throw an exception
        if (newStrData.Length > 1)
        {
            //get only the first letter of the value P,B,T
            result = newStrData.Substring(0, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            result = "";
        }

        if (table.GetLength(0) < xIndex)
        {
            break;
        }

        
        if (result.Equals(newPrevious) || result.Equals("T") && yIndex < table.GetLength(1))
        {
            yIndex += 1;
            table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
        else if (result.Equals(newPrevious) && previous.Equals("T") && yIndex < table.GetLength(1))
        {
            yIndex += 1;
            table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
        else
        {
            xIndex += 1;
            yIndex = 0;
            table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
        previous = result;

        if (!result.Equals("T"))
        {
            newPrevious = previous;
        }

        o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex * 93, yIndex * -93, 0f);
```

Now this code will look like this

[image]

Now if i declare my `xIndex = -1;` it will look like this

[image]

But the real problem is when i start changing my string data like this

```
int xIndex = -1;
string[] strData = { "T  ,T  ,P  ,P B,T  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,T  ,B  ,P  " };
```

It gives me an error

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.

But when i change my `xIndex` to this

```
int xIndex = 0;
```

It will give this output

[image]

## What my expected output must be this

[image]

Comment: I noticed you finally changed to Unity UI. What changed your mind? As for your question, note that you can't  access array element with a negative index value.

Comment: This looks weird: `string[] strData = { "B  ,T  ,P  ,P B,T  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,T  ,B  ,P  " };` Wonder if did you mean `string[] strData = { "B"  ,"T"  ,"P"  ,"P", "B","T"  ,"B"  ,"B"  ,"B"  ,"B"  ,"T"  ,"B"  ,"P" };`

Comment: This is a [crosspost](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/158749/115296) [EDIT: the gamedev post got closed quickly so this one can probably stay open?]. I don't think you're supposed to cross-post to multiple sites. For more info, see [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/388203).

Comment: @Programmer yes i changed it . No one is helping me on using NGUI . Yes i know i can't but its weird that only for the string data `T` that exception appear .

Comment: @bradbury9 how come it wierd ? I split them so no worry about doing this thing "".

Comment: @sonny I'm sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

15 hours without sleeping i came up with this

I added some of this variables

```
string previous = "";
int counterForTie = 0;
int counterForRow = 1;
int justMoveToY = 1;
```

and full of `if` and `else` statements

```
if (result.Equals(newPrevious) || result.Equals("T") && yIndex < table.GetLength(1))
        {
            if (counterForRow == 1)
            {
                yIndex = 0;
                counterForTie++;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
                counterForRow++;
            }
            else { 
                yIndex += 1;
                counterForTie++;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
            }
        }
        else if (result.Equals(newPrevious) && previous.Equals("T") && yIndex < table.GetLength(1))
        {
            yIndex += 1;
            counterForTie++;
            table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
        else
        {
            if (justMoveToY == 1 && counterForRow == 1)
            {
                xIndex = 0;
                yIndex = 0;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
                justMoveToY++;
                counterForRow++;

            }
            else if (justMoveToY == 1)
            {
                xIndex = 0;
                yIndex += 1;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
                justMoveToY++;
            }
            else
            {
                xIndex += 1;
                yIndex = 0;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
                counterForTie = 0;
            }
        }
```

and cut it with this for the positioning of my prefabs.

```
if (counterForTie < 6)
{
    o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex * 93, yIndex * -93, 0f);
}
else
{
    int reminder = counterForTie % 5;
    o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3((xIndex + reminder) * 93,  -465, 0f);
}
```

and lastly get rid of the `ExceptionError : Array out of index`

```
int xIndex = 0;
```

and forcing it to be on the first row first column of my board

```
if (counterForRow == 1)
{
    yIndex = 0;
    counterForTie++;
    table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
    counterForRow++;
 }
 else { 
     yIndex += 1;
     counterForTie++;
     table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
 }
```

Though i still have a problem with this but this is a big step for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the array index using a negative integer, which is simply not allowed in most of the programming languages. Hence the `IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range" error.`

Comment: yes i know but its weird that it only comes out if i changed the first string value to T